# SQL - Date stored as varchar but formatted as Julian Date

Tags: sql, datetime

I've browsed around at similar posts and haven't quite found my exact issue. Basically I just started my job at a company that is building their database out with contractors right now. Every single one of our date fields are stored in a Julian format "20190101", but they're formatted as a Varchar instead of DateTime.

This is obviously problematic for using date related functions in SQL. Ultimately I plan on holding our contractors feet to the fire and telling them to change it. But based on my research, I can't find any real reason that a database would get created without using DateTime format for dates other than laziness.

Is there any legitimate reason to store date time formats as varchar? And secondly, if this is what I'm stuck with, could anyone enlighten me on what I can do to make this into a workable format? Most of my queries I'm going to want to have pulling data for the previous 365 - 730 days.

I'm currently getting the error message "The Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out of range value." on the following line of code:

`WHERE Promise_Date > DATEADD(year,-1, GETDATE())`

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server? Additionally, '20190101' is not a Julian date.

Comment: SQL Azure is what we're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find where the conversion fails:

```
SELECT Promise_Date
FROM t
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, Promise_Date) IS NULL;
```

In the meantime, make the conversion explicit:

```
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, Promise_Date) > DATEADD(year,-1, GETDATE())
```

In general, there is not a good reason for storing the data as a string.  If you do use a string, then YYYYMMDD is a very good choice.  SQL Server will always correctly convert it.  In your case, you have bad values.

There may be some cases where dates and non-dates need to be stored in the same field. For instance, I once worked in an environment where derivatives were priced on a particular date -- but they could also be specified as "NYC close" or "London open" or something similar, to indicate "business" dates.

Comment: The second option you gave me works. I actually just spoke with our contractor, and I was actually querying off our staging database; they said they plan on making the appropriate formatting changes on the live version.